# integration of a exponential function

Tags: integration

$$\int_0^R \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{1+cv}e^{-cu} r\,dr\,d\theta$$

where $u=r^\alpha$, $v=\dfrac{k r^\alpha}{(r^2+d^2-2rd\cos\theta)^{\alpha/2}}$ and $c$ is a constant.

I've been trying to integrate this function quiet a few times for my current project, however, i'm not getting any results. Any suggestions ?

Comment: I believe it should be $d\theta \; dr$ instead

Comment: yes, any suggestions?